# GitHub - Composer Installation to Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, github, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

Hi I just want to ask how would i install something i found in github that requires composer installation to cakephp? i already installed composer and (i think) it's working though i havent tested it because i don't know how. But basically my question is how i would use this ..

```
{
    "require": {
    "kronusme/dota2-api": "2.2.1"
    }
}
```

to install that repo to my project? i mean where should i type that or something. sorry if this is a very basic question. thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you have already cloned or downloaded the necessary files, then you can use command prompt. Change the directory to your folder then assuming you have composer installed type `composer install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are couple of ways:*

**First:** Simply go to the respective folder (eg:E:\xampp\htdocs\composerTest) in command prompt and write:

```
composer require "kronusme/dota2-api:*"
```

Which will download the latest versions of dota1-api in the respective path you have provided. And this is probably the easiest way.

**Second:** Save following things on composer.json file within the respective folder(eg:E:\xampp\htdocs\composerTest)

```
{
   "require": {
    "kronusme/dota2-api": "2.2.1"
  }
}
```

And now just go to respective location from Command prompt and write:

```
composer install
```

This will also download the file into the path you have provided.

Comment: amazing. It worked great. thank you so much for answering. :)